# Old non-existent Julia kernel still appearing in Jupyter after upgrade to 1.8, and rebuild of IJulia package

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Upgraded Julia to 1.8. Ran "build IJulia" to update the package. New kernel visible in Jupyter, but so is the old one (that version of Julia is removed from system).
[image]
How can I get rid of this non existent Julia kernel?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the name of that kernel with `jupyter kernelspec list` (probably `julia-1.7`). Then run

```
jupyter kernelspec remove julia-1.7
```

(with the actual name of the kernel in place of `julia-1.7`, in case it's different), and answer `y` to the confirmation prompt.

Comment: That is a good answer, but there is an error-- you check the name of the kernel with ```jupyter kernelspec list```.  Replacing ```jupyter notebook list``` with ```jupyter kernelspec list``` would fix it.